# Displaying a ViewController from a TabView modally

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller, tabview

I am trying to create a tabview project with three tabs (A,B,C). Tabs A and C are tableview controllers which work well. Tab B I want to make a ViewController that will use the camera using a AVCaptureSession. The question I have is how do I make Tab B display the camera modally over the tabview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just present any modal controller without animation in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];  // for testing
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

In that view controller you can do whatever you like, including starting a AVCaptureSession.

In order to return to the previously selected tab controller there are several options.

One is to switch to the desired tab when dismissing the modal view controller. Suppose it has a property or ivar called `lastTab`:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController 
  = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:lastTab];
```

Another way is to never actually activate the tab with the modal view but launch the modal view controller directly from the other tabs. The other view controller could set the selected tab back to itself and then launch the modal view.

Comment: That is quite a different problem from the one you asked. I added to my answer.

Comment: I used similar code to what you provided above to present a modal view controller for the AVCapture session over the Tab B, but when I dismiss the controller it takes me back to Tab B. What I am looking for is that when a user presses Tab B when in Tabs A or C, a modal view controller is displayed over the Tab they are currently in, so if a user chooses to cancel out of the camera they are returned to the window they were previously in. I am looking for Tab B to work as a button that calls for the modalviewcontroller to be presented, but I can't find a way to put a button in the tabviewbar